# Font size of Figure Caption Header

Tags: captions, fontsize

My question is about changing the font size.

I have to insert two figures side by side. Coming to inserting the captions for the figures individually:

```
Figure 3: blah blah.....................Figure 4: blah blah...
```

I am able to change the font size of "blah blah". What I want to know is how to change the font size of "Figure 3" or "Figure 4", say the figure headers or something. I do not know what they are called to search on-line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) While cmhughes' answer is a very good one some classes like [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) or [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) have their own ways to do these things which is why a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be a good addition to your question.

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark) is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 176):

You can do this (and more!) with the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) package

```
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
```

will make `Figure` in bold, and make the caption content `small`.

Referencing Section 2.3 of the documentation, the size options for `font` are as follows:

- `scriptsize`
- `footnotesize`
- `small`
- `normalsize`
- `large`
- `Large`

Here's a MWE to play with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{My caption here}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{My other caption here}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.... I do not know its not working for me...I am actually using Lyx...I tried writing this command in preamble its not working either

Comment: @JeshwanthKundem you're welcome :) When you say 'not working', does that mean not producing the output, or not compiling, or something else? Perhaps an update is in order: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: its compiling..I mean to say..i am not getting what I want...you understood my question right...the part "Figure 3"  I need to change the font of this

Comment: @JeshwanthKundem It [_should_ work in LyX, too](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=22099). You should perhaps read the [`caption` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) to find out which options you need.

Comment: @cmhughes Its working..I figured out how to add the permeable...Thank you very much...

Comment: @JeshwanthKundem great, glad it's fixed :) if this finishes the question, then please consider accepting my answer by using the green check mark, and upvoting my answer once you have enough reputation to do so :) welcome!

Comment: Can the size be custom? I am looking for smaller than scriptsize

Comment: What If I need to set the caption as `\fontfamily{phv}`  and `\fontsize{11}{10}`?

Comment: And how do you change the font in the referenced text? I would like to see Figure 1 italiced

Comment: New questions are encouraged/fine

Comment: One can do `\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{subcaption}` to make this work on `subfigures` as well.

Comment: The effect of `labelfont=bf` is to make the figure label, but not the entire caption appear in bold font.

Comment: How can you change the size of specific captions? For example I only want to do this on the figures that are side by side?

Answer (score 26):

Not sure why but the answer above did not work for me. If that's the case for you, simply declare:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
```

For more detail see: [Changing Figure caption text size.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234777/changing-figure-caption-text-size).

Comment: in `sciposter` documentclass, it doesn't have any effect, either