# Changing Figure caption text size.

Tags: graphics, captions, fontsize

How can I change the size of text for figure captions?

Currently my code looks like,

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Image.png}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

This makes the Caption in the same size and font as the bulk text of my document. Ideally I would like it to be smaller.

Comment: Have a look at the [`caption`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) package.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `caption` package and declare:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{font=Large,labelfont=Large}
```

to have your figure captions with `\Large` font, for example.

Available values are `scriptsize`, `footnotesize`, `small`, `normalsize`, `large`, and `Large`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=Large,labelfont=Large}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`labelfont` is only really needed if you want different formatting for the caption label and the caption itself.

Comment: Is there any way to set the font size to a specific one apart from the predefined fontsizes? Something like `\captionsetup[figure]{font=25}`