# Setting up different font sizes for captions in each figure

Tags: captions, fontsize, subcaption

I try to change font sizes od figures caption separately for some figures.
I read that: [Changing Figure caption text size.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234777/changing-figure-caption-text-size)
But using this solution sets it globally for whole document not for selected figures. Is it possible to set different fontsizes for each figures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the `\captionsetup{}` inside of the figure-environment instead of in the preamble, then only the 'selected' figure is affected.