# Why the table number is much smaller than the caption

Tags: tables, pdftex, lyx

I am using lyx. I am not sure why my tables looks like this

[image]

The "Table 1" is much smaller compared to my caption and table content. I set the normal size to 10 pt in lyx, and use large in caption and contents. I am not sure how to change the "table 1" into large in lyx. The only preamble I am using is geometry. The document class is elsevier.

Comment: What document class are you using? Can you include a minimal.lyx file?

Comment: Perhaps (I don't know Lyx) load the `caption` package, and use `\captionsetup{labelfont=normalsize}`?

Comment: @Bernard Well,`labelfont=large` I guess, considering that the caption and table contents appear to be set in a large font.

Comment: @Bernard It worked. I load the package, and set the label to large. Works like a magic. Thanks !

Comment: @Torbjørn T: It's hard to guess a font size from an image!

Comment: Would you be OK with closing this question as a duplicate of [Font size of Figure Caption Header](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86120), even though that doesn't include LyX?

Comment: Sure. I dont mind

Comment: It seems that the elsevier document class is incompatible to the caption package (and vice versa), but Lyx does load the caption package anyway?

Comment: @Alex I guess so.