# Fontsize of captions of the whole dissertation

Tags: captions, fontsize

I am using my university template. I noticed that the captions may have the same fontsize as the text. I don't know how to set fontsize of captions of all figures and tables throughout the dissertation as 11pt instead of 12pt.

Comment: See the `caption` package please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this will answer your question. I didn't want to copy/paste since it's not my own work.
[Font size of Figure Caption Header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86120/font-size-of-figure-caption-header)