# Reducing caption font size

Tags: floats, xetex, captions, fontsize

I would like to see the caption font (and caption label too) with size that is smaller than in whole document.

I`ve tried some solutions from SE ([Font size of Figure Caption Header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86120/font-size-of-figure-caption-header)), e.g.:

```
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
```

and

```
\usepackage{caption}
...
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
```

but is doesn`t work in my case.

I think it may be caused by one of this conditions or both:

1. I`m using *extarticle* document class (because I need 14pt text size);
2. I have the following lines in my code (that centering captions of figures):

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\parbox{1\textwidth}{\begin{center}#1: #2\end{center}}\hfill}
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
```

Can you give me some advices about my problem? In addition, how can I manually derive caption font size (for example 12pt or 13pt)?

**Update.** here is the MWE of my problem (I hope it`s actualy "M"inimal):

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {pictures/} }

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\parbox{1\textwidth}{\begin{center}#1: #2\end{center}}\hfill}
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Picture:
\begin{figure}[ht]
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{levels.png}
    \caption{Here is a big picture. Caption are centered but it has the same font size as in whole document.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried to insert the desired fontsize in your definition of the caption? It is easier to help you, if you provide for an MWE.

Comment: @C.Peters, please, take a look at the updated version of my question with MWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already redefining `\@makecaption`, you can set the size there (and that's likely why you're finding that the `caption` package isn't working as expected).

I'd also note that your definition can be improved a bit. The nested `\hbox to\textwidth` and `\parbox` are redundant and you can actually get rid of both. You probably want to also not use the `center` environment as that adds a bit of vertical space above and below since it's implemented using a `trivlist`.

Instead I would do this:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  {
   \centering
   \small % or whatever your desired size is
   #1: #2
   \par % otherwise the centering will go away before it gets applied to the caption
  }
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpfull suggestions! However, I have one unanswered question: is there a way to set font size in caption manually in points (pt) instead of commands like \small etc.?

Comment: Yes. In fact the sizing commands are a relic of the earliest era of LaTeX where fonts were typically only available at a limited set of (idiosyncratic) sizes. The command `\fontsize{9pt){11pt}\selectfont` will, for example, set the size to be 9pt on an 11pt baseline. Note that `\small` also adjusts some other parameters but they shouldn't come into play in the context of a caption.

Comment: I leave here a note: do not forget to remove `[fontsize=small]` while including package `caption`. I've missed it and lost some time figuring it out.